# How to initialize JRockit MBean tree

Tags: java, initialization, jmx, jrockit

I have the following code that just lists all MBean names found in platform MBean server:

```
  public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

    initJMX();

  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  private static void initJMX() throws IOException, MalformedURLException, AttributeNotFoundException,
      InstanceNotFoundException, MalformedObjectNameException, MBeanException, ReflectionException,
      NullPointerException {
    JMXConnector jmxc = null;
    final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.newJMXConnector(createConnectionURL("localhost", 7788), map);
    jmxc.connect();
    final MBeanServerConnection connection = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();
    final String[] domains = connection.getDomains();
    for (final String domain : domains) {
      final Set<ObjectName> mBeans = connection.queryNames(new ObjectName(domain + ":*"), null);
      for (final ObjectName name : mBeans) {
        System.out.println(name);
      }
    }
    jmxc.close();
  }
```

When I try to run this code with JRockit 1.5.0_4.0.1 with the following parameters:

```
-Xmanagement:ssl=false,authenticate=false,autodiscovery=false,port=7788
```

And it prints the following list:

```
[INFO ][mgmnt  ] Remote JMX connector started at address localhost:7788 
[INFO ][mgmnt  ] Local JMX connector started
com.oracle.jrockit:type=FlightRecorder
java.util.logging:type=Logging
JMImplementation:type=MBeanServerDelegate
java.lang:type=Compilation
java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=Garbage collection optimized for throughput Young Collector
java.lang:type=MemoryManager,name=Class Manager
java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=ClassBlock Memory
java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=Garbage collection optimized for throughput Old Collector
java.lang:type=Runtime
java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=Nursery
java.lang:type=ClassLoading
java.lang:type=Threading
java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=Class Memory
java.lang:type=OperatingSystem
java.lang:type=Memory
java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=Old Space
```

But if I put a breakpoint before a call to initJMX method and at that point connect to that JVM with JRMC, then JRMC displays much more MBeans and also after I continue program execution it also prints a different list which contains more JRockit related MBeans:

```
[INFO ][mgmnt  ] Remote JMX connector started at address T500W7AAD:7788 
[INFO ][mgmnt  ] Local JMX connector started
com.oracle.jrockit:type=FlightRecorder
oracle.jrockit.management:type=PerfCounters
oracle.jrockit.management:type=Compilation
oracle.jrockit.management:type=Log
oracle.jrockit.management:type=Profiler
oracle.jrockit.management:type=MemLeak
oracle.jrockit.management:type=JRockitConsole
oracle.jrockit.management:type=GarbageCollector
oracle.jrockit.management:type=Runtime
oracle.jrockit.management:type=Threading
oracle.jrockit.management:type=DiagnosticCommand
oracle.jrockit.management:type=Memory
java.util.logging:type=Logging
JMImplementation:type=MBeanServerDelegate
java.lang:type=Compilation
java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=Garbage collection optimized for throughput Young Collector
java.lang:type=MemoryManager,name=Class Manager
java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=ClassBlock Memory
java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=Garbage collection optimized for throughput Old Collector
java.lang:type=Runtime
java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=Nursery
java.lang:type=ClassLoading
java.lang:type=Threading
java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=Class Memory
java.lang:type=OperatingSystem
java.lang:type=Memory
java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=Old Space
```

Is there a way to say JRockit to initialize those beans automatically on JVM startup without a need of explicit JRMC connection? The problem is that I'm trying to write some code that reuses some of those MBeans, but they are not available until I connect with JRMC.

**UPDATE**: This seems to be JRockit jdk1.5.0_4.0.1 problem. As same code works as expected on JRockit jdk6.0_4.1.0.

Comment: Beware that the oracle* and com.oracle* mbeans are not supported for access outside JRMC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with the Windows version of JRockit that I use:

```
java version "1.5.0_24"
Java(TM) Platform, Standard Edition for Business (build 1.5.0_24-b02)
Oracle JRockit(R) (build R28.0.1-21-133393-1.5.0_24-20100512-2131-windows-x86_64, compiled mode)
```

Same code works as expected on latest JRockit for JDK 1.6.0 on Windows:

```
java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11)
Oracle JRockit(R) (build R28.2.2-7-148152-1.6.0_29-20111221-2104-windows-x86_64, compiled mode)
```

and on the same JRockit version, but for Linux:

```
java version "1.5.0_24"
Java(TM) Platform, Standard Edition for Business (build 1.5.0_24-b02)
Oracle JRockit(R) (build R28.1.0-123-138454-1.5.0_24-20101014-1350-linux-x86_64, compiled mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

try your query with object names of `*:*`

```
final Set<ObjectName> mBeans = connection.queryNames(new ObjectName("*:*"),
```

Maybe there is more than one MBeanServer in the JRockit that the JRMC finds all MBeanServers.

Comment: it gives the same result. besides in the code above I already iterate through all available domains.